# Certain Google Chrome extensions seem to interfere with bootstrap's .modal() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have the following simple code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btntest').click(function () {
        jQuery('#modal').modal();
    });
});
```

I'm including bootstrap and using its `.modal()` method to open a modal box when clicking on a button. This works in all browsers, but for some reason seems to enter in a conflict with certain Google Chrome plugins. The two extensions I had active that would do this were "Responsive Web Design Tester" and "Hide My AdBlocker". Whenever I would have them installed and activated, the modal would not show up and the following message would appear in the JavaScript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).modal is not a function

Why does this happen, and how could I fix this conflict?

Comment: How do you load your scripts? jQuery first then Bootstrap? That should be the proper order because bootstrap relies on jQuery

Comment: I agree with Amir, but also are you certain that #modal has been defined?  Maybe `console.log($('#modal'));` to ensure it is there and available.

Comment: Yes. jQuery is loaded first, and then Bootstrap. I've even included them in the header to make extra sure they're available when the Javascript is loaded. This problem only happens when I have these specific Chrome extension activated.